# MKPolygon with holes

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I searched over the internet but I couldn't find an answer to this. It is possible to draw a hole in a MKPolygon? Something like this:

[image]

I remember I saw something like this, but I'm not sure if it was related to iOS. It is possible to do this and (if it is) how I should start?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this properly, you should really look at the `interiorPolygons` parts of [MKPolygon](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolygon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009717).

Answer (score 2):

As @incanus points out, you can define an `interiorPolygons` array. For example:

```
NSUInteger interiorCount = 5;
CLLocationCoordinate2D interiorCoordinates[interiorCount];

interiorCoordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
interiorCoordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
interiorCoordinates[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
interiorCoordinates[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
interiorCoordinates[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);

MKPolygon* interiorPolygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:interiorCoordinates
                                                         count:interiorCount];
interiorPolygon.title = @"interior polygon";

NSUInteger count = 5;
CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinates[count];

coordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
coordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
coordinates[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
coordinates[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);
coordinates[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(...);

MKPolygon* polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates
                                                 count:count
                                      interiorPolygons:@[interiorPolygon]];

polygon.title = @"exterior polygon";
[self.mapView addOverlay:polygon];
```

That yields:

[image: overlay with interior polygon]

Credit goes to @incanus!

Comment: Anyway to add a rounded whole?

Comment: Sure, you could replace that `interiorPolygon` with a many sided equilateral polygon. If there are enough sides to it (e.g. 60? 90? 120? etc.), I suspect it will be visually indistinguishable from a circle. But, no, I don't see anyway to use a `MKCircle` in lieu of the `interiorPolygons`.

Comment: can you make the inside polygons to have a color? basinal the inverse of what you did?

Comment: @pudm - just add another polygon for the center.

Comment: @Rob what i meant is to have polygons only inside a main polygon so basically like holes except polygons and remove everything that is outside

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You should create a graphical representation of what you mean and then post your own question rather than asking in comments here.